# log4net and Sharepoint 2007 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow, log4net

I'm working on a project with some custom Sharepoint Workflow components which I'd like to add log4net to.

I'm really struggling to get log4net to output anything at all though!

Here's my current setup:

In the codebehind for my Workflow:

```
private ILog log;

public MessageQueueWorkflow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4netConfigPath"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(filepath));
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    }

}

public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        #region Logging
        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            log.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
        #endregion Logging

        // do some stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
        {
            log.Error("An error has occurred.", ex);
        }

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In my web.config for the Sharepoint site:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4netConfigPath" value="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\log4net.config"/>
</appSettings>
```

In my log4net.config file:

```
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
    <applicationName value="MyApp" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Now, when I run this workflow, I'd expect to see some debug entries showing up in the EventViewer, but I'm getting nothing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure at least one logger. Usually you would configure the root logger. E.g.:

```
<log4net>
   ...
   <root>
       <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />     
   </root>
</log4net>
```

If this is not making it work yet, the I recommend that you configure a trace listener that will output the log4net internal debugging messages. (You already have internal debugging turned on.)

Comment: Awesome... Thanks Stefan. I'd messed about with the config file fairly extensively, and hadn't noticed that I'd knocked off the <root> node! The tracing was also a good suggestion, and showed me that whatever service ID Sharepoint is running under doesn't have access to use the EventLog. I've changed it to log to a file, and it's working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that whenver workflow goes to sleep (serialized to database) and wakes up, it continues to run within OWSTIMER.EXE process and you will **NO MORE** see any log entries. This also applies for log entries written in event reciever or methods executed by stsadm or any other process than IIS worker process.

So i would recommend you to:

- Put log4net.config in 12Hive/CONFIG directory
- Put log4net.dll in GAC

Then i prefer putting this in my AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = 
    @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\" + 
    @"Web Server Extensions\12\CONFIG\log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

So whatever process will use my assembly, it will get logged (would it be event reciever, stsadm console or SharePoint Manager - it all gets logged).

See [SharePoint and Log4Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219668/sharepoint-and-log4net-) question.